# View .gpg file content

Tags: c, gnupg, gpgme

I'm writing a C application and I wanna know if there is a way to view .gpg file content (then the encrypted content). The .gpg file in question concerns a simple .txt file that I encrypted.
I know a bit GPGME, it's possible with its function? Or other ways...

EDIT: I thought one thing: if my application use "--armor" option, I've a .gpg file in ASCII mode and not binary...so the .gpg file can be read simply, true? The easiest way...

Answer (score 1):

[libgcrypt](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/)

> This is a general purpose
>   cryptographic library based on the
>   code from GnuPG. It provides functions
>   for all cryptograhic building blocks:
>   symmetric ciphers (AES, DES, Blowfish,
>   CAST5, Twofish, Arcfour), hash
>   algorithms (MD4, MD5, RIPE-MD160,
>   SHA-1, TIGER-192), MACs (HMAC for all
>   hash algorithms), public key
>   algorithms (RSA, ElGamal, DSA), large
>   integer functions, random numbers and
>   a lot of supporting functions.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't know libgcrypt...Do you know the exact funtion/s to use for my purpose?

Comment: I'll do. I'll wait other answers too.

Comment: I thought one thing: if my application use "--armor" option, I've a .gpg file in ASCII mode and not binary...so the .gpg file can be read simply, true? The easiest way...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GnuPG Made Easy](http://www.gnupg.org/gpgme.html) library, here is a [mini howto](http://www.dewinter.com/gnupg_howto/english/GPGMiniHowto.html) on using it.